# What is the better approach for recursive function returning boolean values

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

I was practicing linked-list problem: search element using recursion in Java and was just curious to know which approach is better?

A:

```
protected boolean searchElement(Node current, int element){
    boolean res = false;
    if(current != null){
        if(current.getData() == elem) res = true;
        else function(current.getNext(),elem);
    }
    else res = false;
    return res;
}
```

B:

```
protected boolean searchElement(Node current, int elem){
  if(current != null){
    if(current.getData() == elem) return true;
    else search(current.getNext(), elem);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what output you are trying to achieve from this code?

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's specific Java-hackish bytecode injection optimization reasons for using `end-recursion`/`tail-call` strategy in recursive functions, I would even go for this (fail-fast-fail-early):

```
protected boolean function(arguments){
  if(!condition_1) return false;
  if(condition_2) return true;
  return function(arguments);
}
```

BTW you may have an error in your pseudo code:
In both A and B, the handling of

```
else function(arguments);
```

looks inconsequential. It will run the function, but both implementations will return false, no matter what `function()` does (unless it throws an uncaught exception/throwable). This indicates either

- a mistake in programming,
- or some side-effects (changing exterior state variables such as static or member variables), which recursive functions rather should NOT do

If this is only a mistake in programming/design, I suggest you always translate pseudocode into real code. This way the compiler will usually tell you such things, make them more evident. Amp up your clean code / code smell warning settings.

Oh, and another note to consider: you can always replace recursive functions with a loop and some variables/lists, which usually drastically increases speed (no creation and release of stack frames when running) but often reduces readability (multiple variables to mess up, instead of cleanly assigned parameters).
For your example, as the impact of the call to `function()` is unclear, I cannot present you a meaningful example here.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer handling the special cases first, then the recursion (as far as feasible).
This in a code style with several returns - which many do not find good style.
But it prevents nested conditions and else.

```
protected boolean searchElement(Node current, int element) {
    if (current == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (current.getData() == elem) {
        return true;
    }
    return search(current.getNext(), elem);
}
```

1. Case: terminating condition on null node.
2. Case: found.
3. Recursion, here last, so called *tail recursion*.

Tail recursion can be easily transformed to iteration.

```
protected boolean searchElement(Node current, int element) {
    while (current != null) {
        if (current.getData() == elem) {
            return true;
        }
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You've make a mistake on your first example. It must be 'if (current == null) { return false; }'

Comment: with a bit of modification